# Chrome cannot convert date string to date in format YYYY/MM/DD PM hh:mm

Tags: google-chrome, date, datetime, internet-explorer-11

I think Chrome is most flexible browser but it is not working in below case:

```
newrecorddate = "2015/10/20 PM 06:09"
var d = new Date(newrecorddate);
console.log("d="+d);
```

In IE11 the date (d) is returned successfully. In Chrome "Invalid Date" is returned. How can I workaround it?

UPDATE:

Dai's code actually solve the problem so it is marked as answer. Here is the code I use:

```
var r = /(\d{4})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2}) (PM|AM) (\d{2})\:(\d{2})/;
                if( newRecordDate.match( r ) ) {
                    var ymd = newRecordDate.split(" ")[0];
                    var tt = newRecordDate.split(" ")[1];
                    var tod = newRecordDate.split(" ")[2];
                    var d = new Date( ymd + " " + tod + " " + tt );
                }

                return d;
```

Comment: PM and AM are almost never listed before the time. This works for me in Chrome: ""2015/10/20 6:09 PM"".

Comment: Oh.. I think Microsoft do it by purpose. The newrecorddate string is provided by SharePoint. Can I convert with JS or Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I worked on Chakra, Microsoft's JavaScript engine)

ECMAScript's specification does not list the formats that `Date`'s constructor must successfully parse, in practice most implementations will generally successfully read almost every non-ambiguous format available, however the format you're using, `YYYY/MM/dd tt HH:mm` is not a format seen in reality (the `tt` is in the middle instead at the end). A good heuristic implementation might be able to guess it but it helps to not have to guess or depend on any feature support not present in the language's specification.

You'll have to parse the date yourself, reformat it, and pass that into `Date`'s constructor, fortunately regex makes this easy:

```
var r = /(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}) (PM|AM) (\d{2})\:(\d{2})/;
if( r.match( newRecordDate ) ) {
    var ymd = newRecordDate.substr( 0, 10 ); // note substr instead of substring
    var tt  = newRecordDate.substr( 11, 2 );
    var tod = newRecordDate.substr( 14, 5 );

    var d = new Date( ymd + " " + tod + " " + tt );
}
```

That should work. Untested though.

Comment: FYI, I am using SP2013 with Chinese language pack. The datestring come from SharePoint. I think the language pack make the "tt" sit in the middle instead of the end. (As a Chinese, I am not sure why they have the funny idea)

Comment: @Mark The strange date format is likely a bug in SharePoint.

Comment: ya, but when test with non-Chinese settings the datetime has no problem. So probably this problem will not be fixed =(